# Summing and subtracting in Linq to Sql

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Hello all I want to achieve something like the SQL Select statement with Linq to Sql. Any help will be appreciated.

```
SELECT SUM(Debit-Credit) AS LBalance FROM dbo.LeaveLedger
WHERE StaffId =1 AND LYEAR='2000'
```

Comment: Is this Linq to SQL, or Entity framework? Your question mentions both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming Entity Framework:

```
Context.Table.Where(x => x.StaffId == 1 and x.LYEAR == "2000")
   .Sum(y => (y.Debit - y.Credit));
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a .Sum() at the end

Comment: @AD.Net Right you are :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
var sum = 
    db.LeaveLedger
      .Where(ll => ll.StaffId == 1 and ll.LYEAR == "2000")
      .Sum(ll => (ll.Debit - ll.Credit))
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Mansfield has already shown the expression syntax, I'll have a go with the classic query:

```
var LBalance = (from p in dbo.LeaveLedger
                where p.StaffId == 1 && p.LYEAR == "2000"
                select (p.Debit - p.Credit).Sum();
```

Comment: I think you'll have to reference `LBalance` in the `Sum()` since you've put in inside an anonymous object.

Comment: righto! Then just without an anonymous type. I think LBalance should be of type nullable decimal

Comment: According to the documentation of Sum(), yep. `Func<T,Decimal?>`